# Order of Externally Loaded Swf

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I'm loading swf's via an XML file. I'm wanting them to be added onto the stage in the same order that they appear in the XML. The problem that I'm having is that they are added to the stage only when they are fully loaded.

Any ideas how I can get around this.

---

This is my xml (_config.xml)

```
    <campaign>
        <component SWFsource="logo.swf"/>
        <component SWFsource="gallery.swf"/>
        <component SWFsource="video.swf"/>
        <component SWFsource="poll.swf"/>
        <component SWFsource="facebook.swf"/>
    </campaign>
```

My AS3 code

```
var loaders:Array = []; // an Array of loaders instead of a single loader
var xml:XML;
var xmlList:XMLList;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("components.xml"));
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    xml = XML(event.target.data);
    xmlList = xml.children();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < xmlList.length(); i++)
    {
        var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader(); // local instead of member variable
        swfLoader.load(new URLRequest(xmlList[i].@SWFsource));
        swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, loaderInitHandler);
    }
}

function loaderInitHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var swfInfo:LoaderInfo = event.target as LoaderInfo;
    var swfLoader:Loader = swfInfo.loader; 
    if (loaders.length > 0) {
        var lastLoader : Loader = loaders[loaders.length-1]; 
        swfLoader.y = lastLoader.y + lastLoader.height + 10; // positioning happens here
    }
    addChild(swfLoader);
    loaders.push(swfLoader);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is add the Loaders to the stage immediately after creating them, even when their content has not been loaded yet. That way the loaded content ends up being stacked in the order by which they appear in the XML file.

```
{
   var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader(); // local instead of member variable
   swfLoader.load(new URLRequest(xmlList[i].@SWFsource));
   swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, loaderInitHandler);
   addChild(swfLoader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot control the order in which the SWFs will be loaded you'll have to:

Wait until they are **all loaded**, and **then add them to the stage** in the desired order.